# String search algorithm to tell if a text is meaningful

Tags: algorithm

I am decrypting an old text, and I want a fast algorithm to check if in a long string there are meaningful words, from a dictionary. That way I can tell if a specific key has worked.

So, OK with dictionary preprocessing and large table, but as fast as possible on some 25-50 characters.

Thanks!

## Update

I know the language (Italian) but the text is without spaces and maybe with a couple of random letters. Like:

> TANKSSEENNEARUDINEYESTERDAY

And the cipher is a strange columnar transposition, so the single letters frequencies are fixed.

Comment: If you are able to tokenise the string, you're almost home. Tokenise it (whitespace, interpuction) and compare the words to a dictionary (hash table) of well known / common words. A simple heuristic (e.g. 50 % matches) will probably be good enough. This will only work of course if you know the plaintext's language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A standard approach in cryptography would not to check against a dictionary, but to check against a probabilistic model of the (assumed) language of the plaintext. For example, simple statistics for **trigraphs**, i.e. sequences of three characters next to others, are significantly different e.g. between English and gibberish. (In English, "THE" is the most commonly occurring trigraph. Similarly, trigraphs like "CXC" do not occur in English at all.)

For example, Vigenere ciphers can be cracked by inferring key length with a simple autocorrelation scheme and then searching for the actual key based on language statistics of the underlying plaintext language. I even implemented the procedure for demonstration purposes when I was lecturing cryptography at our University... :)

The good thing about using these types of probabilistic / Markov models is that they also tolerate well words that happen to be outside the particular dictionary, or have typos, or are of alternative or archaic forms.

Comment: That seem really interesting, but will it work with only 50 characters? And consider that different words, when near, will form strange trigrams, like `KSS` in my example above.

Comment: Yes it should work with only 50 characters :) Try it :) Human tongues are very redundant. E.g. people can read English text where every second letter has been removed :) The redundancy of human tongues means that they can be easily differentiated from gibberish using statistical methods like trigraph frequencies.

Comment: N.B. To build e.g. the trigraph frequency table you need to have some "corpus" of Italian language, preferably from the corresponding era. Read in the corpus and build the frequency table from it. You can find online corpora of older texts often from linguistics departments of universities, in this case likely some Italian ones...

Answer (score 3):

Without more details, I'd probably encode the dictionary as a trie, and try to match every position in the haystack string. If you don't know about tries, it's the bestest structure ever for fast dictionary lookups.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to narrow down your specifics. Think about it. if You have long words, say 20-30 chars then you would need all the different permutations of all substrings within this string and compare them against a dictionary. That would be very heavy computation. Also if you have a lot of these long words then, unless you run this on a cluster or something, it's going to be pretty difficult.